# paypal express (or any express option) - magento - "terms and conditions"

Tags: magento, paypal, amazon-web-services, google-checkout

UPDATED

(Option One):

In magento, at Step 6 of One Page Checkout you see Terms and Conditions.

Now the problem:

Using PayPal Express Checkout (or any express option e.g. Amazon Payments, Google Checkout) there is no Terms and Conditions for the user to agree to.

I need to:

A. Call Magento "Terms and Conditions" block into a modal window (i don't know how + might be too intrusive?)

B. use -- fake -- express checkout buttons and fake/not-magento-native "Terms and Conditions" on Cart Page that user must agree to - before proceeding to: any Express Checkout.

Goal:

User clicks and any express checkout option on cart page >

User encounters popup that has "Terms and Conditions" they must agree to >

Until they agree (probably via ticking a check-box) the real express checkout button is grayed out (or something similar) >

User agrees and then the real express checkout button is active >

User clicks express button and completes express checkout.

go to:

http://pro-tools-training.com/new-magento2/index.php/highslide#

My question is about how to swap the real express checkout buttons on the cart page for fake ones (just images with some sort of onclick event) and then how to place the real express checkout buttons in the popout.

--

<strike>(Option Two):
here is another option I am looking at.</strike>

i created a static block with a Terms form and assigned a Widget to “PayPal Review Order page”

OK so it shows up but of course its in the wrong place and it does not interact with the Place Order button.

Pros: could work for paypal
Cons: at this point, it’s not an obvious solution for other express checkout buttons

so my fist post tries to address this before hand and this post tries to address it at the last stage.

Option 2 appears too limited. I am now looking closer at option one.

...any feedback helpful

UPDATE THREE:

I'm sure there are many other ways to do this but I came up with this if it will help anyone out there.

go to this page:

http://pro-tools-training.com/new-magento3/index.php/html5-video.html

add to cart > got to cart > click paypal express button

and see i made a popout for express buttons

In  general, you can see the code with firebug but it is just (highslide based)
JavaScript firing a popout and the popout contents are written in shortcut.phtml (for paypal exress) and each express button type has its own .phtml file that is similar (e.g. googlecheckout i used link.phtml).

OPEN ISSUES:

<strike>1. On iPhone (my iPhone anyway) the popout launches but the checkout buttons are missing.</strike> SOLVED: All I needed to do was adjust the width in the js config and the width of the text area in the html.

1. I want to make the same "terms and conditions" on onestep checkout page - but not a popout.  i want it hidden unless the user clicks the paypal radio button. then it appears - in page - and is required to proceed.

any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is solved in the Magento 1.11.2.0: After the PayPal page, the T&Cs are displayed on the order review page.